# Callable and Networkmainthread Error

Tags: android, multithreading, executorservice, future, callable

I'm doing some networking operation and as you know with honeycomb they should be done on another thread instead UIthread otherwise it gives networkmainthread error. In my case I have to get return value from api and do something with it so I decided to use Callable. I'm sending a request and getting the response in call() method but at the end it still gives me networkmainthread error. Where should I make mistake? Any advice will be very appreciated.

```
    private static <T> T getReader(String url, List<NameValuePair> params, final Class<T> classOfT, final Context _context) {

    T result = null;
    RestApiHelper apiHelper = new RestApiHelper(url, params, _context);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Future<Reader> futureSubmit = executor.submit(apiHelper);

    try {
        Reader reader = futureSubmit.get();
        if (reader != null){
            result = new Gson().fromJson(reader, classOfT);   //I'm getting the exception at this line. 
            .
            .
            .   


//*********************************************
//call method of RestApiHelper class which implemented Callable
//*********************************************
@Override
public Reader call() throws Exception {
    Reader reader = null;
    if(fileUri==null)
        reader = executeNormalPost();
    else
        reader = executeSendFilePost();

    return reader;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that use `AsyncTask` if you are doing networking operation. It is best to handle networking operation.

Comment: as I said I have to get response value and do something with it and this will resume nestedly. Async doesnt solve the problem. On the other hand callable is doing that process already in another thread. What I cant understand is why I get that error, how could callable run on mainthread?